# Google Gantt chart with milliseconds scale, instead of seconds scale

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-visualization

I am creating a Gantt chart representing computer processes instead of human processes, so the scale is at the millisecond level.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a Google Gantt Chart representing the millisecond scale?

What I am thinking of doing is just multiplying all my values by 1000 and then mapping them to seconds, but the problem with that is that the chart will then by labeled as seconds, which is kinda annoying.

Answer (score 1):

This is trickier than I thought. Not sure if this will help anyone, please follow closely.

Say we have a timestamp to the milliseconds like so: 1499211060169.

To scale from milliseconds to seconds, you cannot just multiply a unix timestamp by 1000 (obviously). What you need to do, is take the seconds from the timestamp, and store that as `foo`, (effectively taking the floor of timestamp at the seconds place, and dropping any milliseconds). Separately, take the milliseconds from the timestamp, and multiply by 1000, store that as `bar`. To get your scaled value, sum `foo` and `bar`.

So that looks like:

```
original value: 1499211063169
seconds value:  1499211063000
milliseconds: 169
milliseconds scaled: 169000

scaled value: 169000 + 1499211063000 => 1499211232000
```

It makes sense that the last 3 digits are 000, when you think about it.
Because we need to scale this thing to the second, because whatever system we are using is not granular to the millisecond.

Comment: note that I eventually switched from Gantt chart to a Timeline chart, which was more appropriate for my use case: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

Comment: Switching to Timeline chart eliminated this issue